# Rails with Hadoop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hadoop

I will have huge data to store like corers for resumes and would like to consider hadoop as back end . Is this possible to use it with ruby on rails or just need to consider the redis or mongodb.

any pointer to using rails with hadoop would be useful. Or gem that's make the life easy.

Comment: Did you try searching? There's a number of resources--which to examine really depends on what specifically you're doing.

Comment: I tried a lot of searching .. but as  am new to hadoop , not sure how to start with. There was no question about using hadoop with particularly rails. So i started the question.
Got this one working for me .. https://github.com/infochimps-labs/wukong
But not sure if it can serve all the purpose..

Answer (score 7):

Phil Whelan has a great writeup introducing map reduce with ruby using hadoop:
http://www.bigfastblog.com/map-reduce-with-ruby-using-hadoop

There is a nice little gem out there (Rubydoop) that makes writing hadoop jobs in ruby nice and easy (with jRuby):
https://github.com/iconara/rubydoop

If you need to get more technical, and get into real-time streaming, I've been seeing a lot of use of Casandra + Hadoop + Storm:
http://www.slideshare.net/boneill42/ruby-on-big-dag